# SUMIF, Group by, Aggregate by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add a column to show sum of revenue based on line of business and quarter while keeping the original data as is. Step 2 is to compute %Revenue by dividing original revenue row by the sum of revenue - computing weight.

I can do this easily in excel, but can't figure out in SQL. 
Appreciate the help.

So, in my data, I have 1000 rows. Columns are line of business (as Channel vs. MNC), Quarters (as Q319 and Q419), Revenue, Units and part number.

I tried to sum it using group by function, but it does not work.

```
SELECT 
   FF.Quarter,
   FF.CHANNEL,
   FF.Units,
   FF.Material,
   FF.Revenue,

   SUM (Case When FF.Channel = '02' and FF.Quarter = '2019Q3' then FF.Revenue when FF.Channel = '01' and FF.Quarter = '2019Q3' then FF.Revenue Else 1 End) as Revenue_SUM

   FROM dbo.[Flat File] as FF
   Group by FF.Quarter, FF.Channel, FF.Units, FF.Revenue, FF.Material
```

Expectation is to create a column that calculate % weighting of each of the row as % (revenue divided by sum of revenue).

here is data table and expected result on the side. I want to write a query that keeps original data and add the two columns next to it.

[image: data table and expected result]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Are you sure you are using MySQL?  `dbo` and square braces are usually associated with SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry yes, i am using SQL Server.

Comment: Hello Gordon, I just attached base data and expected result in my post. Are you able to see it? I am trying the query you just attached.  let me see if i get success.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a window function:

```
SELECT FF.Quarter, FF.CHANNEL, FF.Units, FF.Material, FF.Revenue,
       SUM(FF.Revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY FF.Channel, FF.Quarter) as Revenue_SUM
FROM dbo.[Flat File] as FF;
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. let me try out.. Sorry yes i am in SQL Server.

Comment: Gordon,  more complex statement.  can I write like this?    SUM (Case 
  When [FGS Type] = 'PIB' then ((HS_Cost.Cost + Tray_Cost.[Tray Cost])*Units)
  When [FGS Type] = 'Tray' then Tray_Cost.[Tray Cost]*Units
  Else '0' End) over (Partition by FF.Channel, FF.Quarter) as [Std COGS SUM]

Comment: Update:  This syntax works.  thanks a lot.. SUM (Case When [FGS Type] = 'PIB' then ((HS_Cost.Cost + Tray_Cost.[Tray Cost])*Units) When [FGS Type] = 'Tray' then Tray_Cost.[Tray Cost]*Units Else '0' End) over (Partition by FF.Channel, FF.Quarter) as [Std COGS SUM]